# Swift Create file with integrity FileManager

Tags: swift, file, security, storage

I'm currently trying to store some files on my iOS device. The contents of the file are encrypted, but I was wondering if I can append some kind of integrity check to the file as well, preferably using the `FileAttributeKey`.

I tried the following, which doesn't work

```
extension FileAttributeKey {
    static let integrity = FileAttributeKey("NSFileIntegrity")
}

let docs = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let fileName = "test"
let filePath = docs.appendingPathComponent(fileName).path

defer {
    try! FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: filePath)
}

let data = Data("Hello world".utf8)

// This line fails too
// FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: filePath, contents: data, attributes: [.integrity: "SHA256"])

FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: filePath, contents: data, attributes: [:])
do {
    try FileManager.default.setAttributes([.integrity: "SHA256"], ofItemAtPath: filePath)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
print(try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: filePath))
```

So the questions are:

1. Is there a way to create and append a custom `FileAttributeKey` to a file.
2. Is there a (better) way to add integrity checks to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) then you get integrity checks for free. Every time you decrypt, integrity will be checked for you and in case of errors the decryption will fail. Just use a mode like GCM or OCB and you are done.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose you are correct. I am using GCM already. I was just thinking about the hypothetical attack where a valid file would be written to disk, but of course the attacker would then need access to the encryption key, which is less likely than him/her breaking extra integrity...